# Magento 2 add script before closing body tag

Tags: magento2, javascript

What is the proper way to add a script before the closing body tag in magento 2?

I want it to be available to all pages.

**UPDATE:**

I've got in `myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` with:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Theme_Module::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

And the `js.phtml` inside `/Magento_Theme/templates`

Should that be right?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with layout

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="You_Module::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and in js.phtml

```
<script src="//cdn.javascrip.com/test.js" />
```

Comment: Do I need to create a new module for this?
I was trying to override magento_theme default.xml and add this there but to no joy.

Comment: theme should work

Comment: So I've got in myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/  default.xml with 

    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Theme_Module::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
    </referenceContainer>

And the js.phtml inside /Magento_Theme/templates>
Should that be right?
Thanks

Comment: Works, but the answer could be a bit more complete so it's actually a real clear example (files etc.).

Comment: how can i do this in custom module?

Answer (score 3):

Add `referenceContainer` code in layout file

`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Before body end

```
 <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="js.beforebody" as="jsbeforebody" template="Magento_Theme::js/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

For after body start

```
 <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="js.afterbody" as="jsafterbody" template="Magento_Theme::js/js.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Create `js.phtml` template file and put your js script/code in this file.

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/js/js.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

The updated codes in your question is not right. You need to change `Theme_Module` to `Magento_Theme` in the `default.xml`.

### Below is the complete code

In your `myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`, add content

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Add the file `js.phtml` inside directory `myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates`.

In the `js.phtml`, add the js content like below

```
<script>
    ...
</script>
```

Refresh the site cache and you will see the effect.

---

### Additional Tips

#### About the js.phtml content

The js content in Magento2 is another topic, you could find it it in official doc [Calling and initializing JavaScript](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html).

An official example is like below

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'accordion'  // the alias for "mage/accordion"
], function ($) {
    $(function () { // to ensure that code evaluates on page load
        $('[data-role=example]')  // we expect that page contains the <tag data-role="example">..</tag> markup
            .accordion({ // now we can use "accordion" as jQuery plugin
                header:  '[data-role=header]',
                content: '[data-role=content]',
                trigger: '[data-role=trigger]',
                ajaxUrlElement: "a"
            });
    });
});
</script>
```