# How to put script before body in Magento version 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1

I tried to insert in the home page a jquery horizontal slider text scroll. What I need is to insert before body two scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/marquee.js"></script>

<script>
$(function (){
  $('.simple-marquee-container').SimpleMarquee();               
});
</script>
```

What I tried so far is in example in a relative [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102785/magento-2-add-script-before-closing-body-tag).

In my console log I have the below errors and of course it didn't work:

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active jquery-migrate.js:21 
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
```

You can see the full errors log in my site http://magentoeshop.vtsoulis.gr/index.php/

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml file in your module

add below code to it

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="beforebodyScript">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/example-script.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Also second solution is you can put your script in template file add xml code to your action layout file

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```