# how to load css file just before body instead of head

Tags: magento2, theme, css

Below is code of my `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="My_Slider::css/betterslider.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

i want `css` to be loaded `js` before body end tag , how can this be done please help with same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation yet to mark this question as a duplicate or to add this as a comment, but here's a cross-reference to an answer: [Magento 2 add script before closing body tag](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102785/magento-2-add-script-before-closing-body-tag)

Answer (score 2):

1. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

   ```
   <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
       <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="beforebodyend.css.file" template="Magento_Theme::html/before_body_end_css.phtml" />
   </referenceContainer>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/before_body_end_css.phtml

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/betterslider.css')?>">
   ```
3. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/css/betterslider.css

   ```
   .class {
        ....
   }
   ```

**Don't forget to flush the cache.**